# What will happen if pointer is incremented after assigning value to its memory location?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, stack

Consider the following example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char charArr[3] = "c++";
    char *pointer = charArr;
    pointer+=3;
    *pointer = 'q';
    pointer+=1;
    *pointer = 'd';
    printf("%s", charArr);
    return 0;
}
```

I hoped that I would get,
**c++qd**
but I got **c++r**

The value of q gets incremented by 1 and turns to 'r', I tried with other increments and it reflects as per ASCII.

Comment: What you are doing is _undefined_, since you are going outside the bounds of the array...

Comment: You left no space for the null terminator also.

Comment: how did it even compile?

Comment: Why are you using C-style arrays rather than `std::array` or `std::vector`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl - it's C-language, not c++. Just string value is c++.

Comment: @drescherjm - I did that on purpose, I was experimenting with pointers.

Comment: Once you hit Undefined Behavior the result of the program is meaningless.

Comment: @Mirror That's very much *not* obvious. As soon as you use *any* C++ feature, your code becomes C++ and can no longer be compiled as C. And once your code is C++ *anyway* you might as well take advantage and not stick with C stuff.. C and C++ are not variations of the same language; they are *very much* different languages and you need to decide which one you are using.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - read the code again, I haven't used a single c++ feature. It's pure C.

Comment: So don't tag your question with the C++ language tag...

Comment: @Mirror "read the code again, I haven't used a single c++ feature". Then why did you A) tag the question as C++? B) Comment "it's C-language, not c++. Just string value is c++.", which implies that it *is* C++.

Answer (score 1):

`charArr` is only big enough to hold the three characters it is initialized with.  The array can't hold any other characters, and it even doesn't have space for a terminating null byte to make it a proper string.

That means that you're writing past the end of the array.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests as unexpected output.

The array should be at least 6 bytes in length so it can hold the additional characters plus a terminating null byte to make it a string.  You also need to add that null byte.

```
char charArr[6] = "c++";
char *pointer = charArr;
pointer+=3;
*pointer = 'q';
pointer+=1;
*pointer = 'd';
pointer+=1;
*pointer = 0;
```

Comment: I know about null byte, and array declarations. Here I was just experimenting with pointers. I was surprised only because I got 'r', which happens as 'q' got incremented. If it would have resulted in compilation error or dirty result, I wouldn't have cared this much.

Comment: @Mirror UB can result in literally *anything*. The program is broken because you broke the rules of the language and *any* result is valid as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: @Mirror Most likely, `*pointer += 'q'` changed the pointer because the pointer was pointing to itself, `pointer += 1` incremented q to r, then `*pointer = 'd';` set some random memory location to `d`, and you were lucky enough that this all worked in a relatively understandable way and didn't just crash or fly off into orbit.

Comment: @Mirror The fact that you got "r" at the end of the string *is* a dirty result.  It's how UB manifested itself in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are just to point out the location, you are entering the data in less space, so simply increase the length of char array first and then process, however your pointers working well.